# Clojure Fibonacci

Tags: beginner, clojure, fibonacci-sequence

I'm a Clojure novice working through [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com) problems. In [one problem](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/26) I am supposed to create a function that takes a number and returns that number of Fibonaccis. My first thought was to create a function that creates a lazy sequence of Fibonaccis and then just takes however many it needs. Here is what I came up with:

```
(fn [numberOfFibs]
 (defn lazyFib [a b]
   (cons a (lazy-seq (lazyFib b (+ b a)))))
 (take numberOfFibs (lazyFib 1 1)))
```

This did work in my IDE but it wasn't accepted by 4Clojure due to the private defn. defs are not accepted by the website.

How can I refactor this function to remove the defn? And what are the problems with style and readability? Is it easy to reason about the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I refactor this function to remove the defn?

What you are looking for is [`letfn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/letfn). It can be used to locally define a recursive function or corecursive functions. In this case:

```
  (fn [numberOfFibs]
    (letfn [(lazyFib [a b] (cons a (lazy-seq (lazyFib b (+ b a)))))]
      (take numberOfFibs (lazyFib 1 1))))
```

> And what are the problems with style and readability?

You shouldn't use nested `def`s. Behavior is not misleading. Especially it is not scoped in the form it appears and affects the current namespace, as if it was a top level form.

```
=> lazyFib
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: lazyFib in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:42) 
=> (fn [numberOfFibs]
    (defn lazyFib [a b]
      (cons a (lazy-seq (lazyFib b (+ b a)))))
    (take numberOfFibs (lazyFib 1 1)))
#<resistors$eval4432$fn__4433 deneme.resistors$eval4432$fn__4433@49531c8c>
=> lazyFib
#<Unbound Unbound: #'deneme.resistors/lazyFib>
=> ((fn [numberOfFibs]
    (defn lazyFib [a b]
      (cons a (lazy-seq (lazyFib b (+ b a)))))
    (take numberOfFibs (lazyFib 1 1))) 10)
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
=> lazyFib
#<resistors$eval4440$fn__4441$lazyFib__4442 deneme.resistors$eval4440$fn__4441$lazyFib__4442@6d17b6ce>
```

Especially confusing is that just evaluating the `fn` without calling it pollutes the namespace with an unbound name.

> Is it easy to reason about the function?

Other than the nested `defn` it is very understandable.

Comment: Sobieck00, an alternative to `(letfn [(lazyFib ...)] ...)` is `(let [lazyFib (fn [a b] ...)] ...)`.  In this case, I would use `letfn`, as abuzittin gillifirca, suggests, but when I have to combine a local function definition with other local definitions, sometimes I use `let`, because it makes the code slightly more concise.  This is probably a a matter of personal preference, however.

Comment: Thanks @Mars, that would be an excellent new answer. In the comments, though, it is not nearly visible enough. One minor point to fix in your new answer: In order to define a recursive function in `let` bindings we'd need a named `fn` expression as in `(let [lazyFib (fn lazyFib [a b] ...)]`, because left hand side of a binding is not yet available to the right hand side in `let`.

Comment: Thanks abuzittin gillifirca--I didn't know that about recursion in a function defined in a `let`.  I don't consider it a new answer, though--only a stylistic variant on your answer.